# Ajax form not submiting after the first submit event and not re-rendering partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a search form with 4 dropdownlists. Each time the user changes the values, the form submits and new results show within a partial view. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DDLUF").change(function (event) {
            $("#loading").show();
            $("#DDLCidade").empty();
            $("#DDLBairro").empty();
            $("#DDLRua").empty();

            if ($("#DDLUF").val() !== '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/CoberturaPainelRotas/ObterCidadesPorUf',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { uf: $("#DDLUF").val() },

                    success: function (Ddd) {
                        $("#DDLCidade").append("<option value''>SELECIONE</option>");
                        $.each(Ddd, function (i, Cidade) {
                            $("#DDLCidade").append('<option value="' + Cidade.Id + '">' + Cidade.Nome + '</option>');
                        });
                        var form = $(event.target).parents('form');
                        form.submit();
                        $("#DDLCidade").prop('disabled', false);
                        $('#loading').hide();

                    }
                });


            } else {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $("#DDLCidade").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#DDLBairro").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#DDLRua").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#totalUf").text("");
                $("#totalCidade").text("");
            }

        });

        $("#DDLCidade").change(function () {
            $("#loading").show();
            $("#DDLBairro").empty();
            $("#DDLRua").empty();

            if ($("#DDLCidade").val() !== 'SELECIONE') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/CoberturaPainelRotas/ObterBairrosPorCidade',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { cidade: $("#DDLCidade").val() },

                    success: function (Ddd) {
                        $("#DDLBairro").append("<option value''>SELECIONE</option>");
                        $.each(Ddd, function (i, Bairro) {
                            $("#DDLBairro").append('<option value="' + Bairro.Id + '">' + Bairro.Nome + '</option>');
                        });
                        var form = $(event.target).parents('form');
                        form.submit();
                        $("#DDLBairro").prop('disabled', false);
                        $('#loading').hide();
                    }
                });

            } else {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $("#DDLBairro").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#DDLRua").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#totalCidade").text("");
            }

        });

        $("#DDLBairro").change(function () {
            $("#loading").show();
            $("#DDLRua").empty();

            if ($("#DDLRua").val() !== 'SELECIONE') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/CoberturaPainelRotas/ObterRuasPorBairro',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { bairro: $("#DDLBairro").val() },

                    success: function (Ddd) {
                        $("#DDLRua").append("<option value''>SELECIONE</option>");
                        $.each(Ddd, function (i, Rua) {
                            $("#DDLRua").append('<option value="">' + Rua.NomeRua + '</option>');
                        });
                        var form = $(event.target).parents('form');
                        form.submit();
                        $("#DDLRua").prop('disabled', false);
                        $('#loading').hide();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $("#DDLRua").prop('disabled', true);
            }

        });



    });
</script>

<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg 12">
            <h3 class="page-header">Consultar Cobertura</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ConsultarCapacidadeSecundaria", "CoberturaPainelRotas", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "PartialConsultarCobertura" }, new { @id = "formID" }))
                {
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label>Uf:</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.UF , new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["UF"]), "SELECIONE", new { @id = "DDLUF", @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label id="totalUf"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>Cidade:</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Cidade, new SelectList(string.Empty), new { @id = "DDLCidade", @class = "form-control", @disabled = "true" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label id="totalCidade"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>Bairro:</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Bairro, new SelectList(string.Empty), new { @id = "DDLBairro", @class = "form-control", @disabled = "true" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>Rua:</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Rua, new SelectList(string.Empty), new { @id = "DDLRua", @class = "form-control", @disabled = "true" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="PartialConsultarCobertura">
                @{
                    Html.RenderPartial("PartialConsultaCobertura");
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user changes the first dropdownlist, the ajax form submits and the results show. But when the user changes the selected item of the following dropdownlists, the form doesn't submit. Could it be that i need to re-attach the jquery event everytime? What am i doing wrong?

(ASP.MVC 5 BTW)

Comment: It looks like you are clearing the selects and adding the options back to them, so you shouldn't be losing your bindings.  I did notice a typo in your second logic block that is adding an option with `value''`, but so far I haven't spotted anything else.

Comment: I've debugged the jquery code with chrome and the success events do fire. But when it comes to the "form.submit", it doesn't.

Comment: Your markup doesn't look to have any form tags.  Is this accurate?

Comment: I'm using the (Ajax.BeginForm) helper

Comment: What?  Do you or do you not have form elements?  Because `$(event.target).parents('form');` is looking for the parent form tag of the select objects.  If they don't have a parent that is a form they will find nothing to submit on

Comment: No, i don't have form tags as i'm using the Ajax begin form helper. As far as i know, you don't need a form tag if you're using the html or ajax begin form helpers. Or am i wrong? And as i said, the when the user changes the first dropdown, the form does submit.

Comment: Ok, so i'm missing something with what is going on from the example you have given.  One thing you can try, in the case that something outside what you have provided is replacing your elements, is to change your bindings to be delegate bindings instead.  Such as `$(document.body).on('change', "#DDLUF", function (event) {....`

Comment: `Ajax.BeginForm` actually creates a `<form>` tag - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to make it work:

1) Added the 'event' in the change events:

```
$("#DDLCidade").change(function (event) {}
```

2) Removed the Ajax begin form:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg 12">
            <h3 class="page-header">Consultar Cobertura</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label>Uf:</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.UF , new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["UF"]), "SELECIONE", new { @id = "DDLUF", @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label id="totalUf"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>Cidade:</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Cidade, new SelectList(string.Empty), new { @id = "DDLCidade", @class = "form-control", @disabled = "true" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label id="totalCidade"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>Bairro:</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Bairro, new SelectList(string.Empty), new { @id = "DDLBairro", @class = "form-control", @disabled = "true" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>Rua:</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Rua, new SelectList(string.Empty), new { @id = "DDLRua", @class = "form-control", @disabled = "true" })
                        </div>
                    </div>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="PartialConsultarCobertura">
                @{
                    Html.RenderPartial("PartialConsultaCobertura");
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

3) Used another ajax call to populate my partial view:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/CoberturaPainelRotas/ConsultarCapacidadeSecundaria',
     data: { uf: $("#DDLUF").val(), cidade: $("#DDLCidade").val(), bairro: $("#DDLBairro").val(), rua: $("#DDLRua").val() },
     success: function (viewHTML) {
            $("#PartialConsultarCobertura").html(viewHTML);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace this `$("#DDLUF").change(function (event)`

to this `$(document).on('change', '#DDLUF', function (e)`

and the same for the remaining dropdownlists

this is a common issue with ajax refresh as it dynamically creates new content and the events are lost on refresh

if this still didn't work you need to change this `var form = $(event.target).parents('form');`

and try to hardcode it like `var form = $(event.target).parent().parent().parent().childern(...;`

Comment: The problem was that i forgot to pass the event parameter inside the other change function calls. Now it's working. But when the user changes the value of the second dropdownlist, the partial view renders as the whole page. What could be causing this?

Comment: try to put `event.preventDefault()` on the first line of the change function

Comment: oh wait you are mixing up between the ajax.beginform and the ajax request you need to do one of them not both

Comment: could you elaborate more?

Comment: when you do form.submit the ajaxform submits values and it updates the content and everything you did in the ajax request is lost

Comment: why do you submit the form at the first place you already did that in the ajax request

Comment: remove `form.submit();` from each succes function as ajax already submitted your values and got the response back

Comment: if i remove the form.submit, only the dropdowns will be populated, and not the partial view

Comment: use another ajax call to update the partial view instead of ajax.beginform